# TYPO3 fails to write to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, typo3

TYPO3 fails to insert data in its own tables after installation, but doesn't complain about it, e.g. the admin user creation via Install Tool finishes with `User created!`,
but the `be_users` table stays empty.

The server is using:

- Debian 6.0.6
- TYPO3 6.0.2
- PHP Version 5.3.19-1~dotdeb.0
- mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28

**Edit:** What I've tried so far:

**1.** Inserts with MySQL Workbench and the typo3 database user are working. Grants:

`` GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, TRIGGER ON `typo3`.* TO 'typo3_user'@'localhost' ``

**2.** I experimeneted with the `commit` behaviour and added two lines to the `Installer.php`, but without success:

```
// added
$autoCommitOffResult = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query('SET SESSION autocommit = 0;');

// the original non-working insert
$result = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_INSERTquery('be_users', $insertFields);

// added
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query('commit;');
```

**3.** I removed the strict `sql_mode`.

**4.** Another Typo3 installation on a very similar server succeeded.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: can you provide any logfile content associated with this problem?

Comment: @ChristianSchaefer: It seems like TYPO3 only logs to the DB and the configuration to change it to file logging is also in the DB ^^

Comment: What permissions does the MySQL user used by TYPO3 have?

Comment: are you able to insert data manually into user table  i mean using some query in mysql client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default engine of MySQL is InnoDB. Changing the engine for the Typo3 tables to MyISAM fixes the problem:

```
ALTER TABLE be_users ENGINE = MyISAM;
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following around the line which doesn't work (2 lines before, 4 lines below):

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debugOutput = true;
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->store_lastBuiltQuery = true;

// Now the line which should insert the BE User:
// the original non-working insert
$result = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_INSERTquery('be_users', $insertFields);

// Now print out the "insert_id" (uid autoincrement value) and query which has been executed:
echo $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_insert_id();
echo "<br />\n";
echo $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debug_lastBuiltQuery;
exit();
```

Then try to copy&paste this query to the mysql shell. As with any problem make sure you use the same server, database, etc.

The exit takes care that no other code will remove the new user directly after creation.

Comment: Of course without the "commit" stuff of previous suggestions.
And tell me what the result is.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds interesting. I'll give it a try asap and tell you about it.

Comment: BTW: Usually "commit" should be required nowhere in TYPO3. The T3 core got developed before mysql started to support the SQL "commit" feature and I don't think the classical T3 will support it in the near future. Don't know about NEOS.

Comment: Did you make any further investigations. I would be interested myself what is going wrong. Usually such a thing shouldn't occur.

Comment: I've added your code. The output is
`25
INSERT INTO be_users (username,password,admin,uc,fileoper_perms,tstamp,crdate) VALUES ('admin','098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6','1','','0','1362156993','1362156993')` but still without success

Comment: The id is incremented on a second try. What more likely to suggest that the cause of the problem is on the side of the MySQL server or the connector.

Comment: the bounty is running out. The problem isn't fixed yet. because your approaches were most helpful, I reward them. Any idea what else I should try? Maybe connect to another db instance..

Answer (score 1):

Are you `commit`ting the transaction?

Comment: Turn it off and do an explicit commit?

Comment: I added two lines to the `Installer.php`, but without success:

`$autoCommitOffResult = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query('SET SESSION autocommit = 0;');`

`$result = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_INSERTquery('be_users', $insertFields);`

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query('commit;');`